# Backpropagation for rectified linear unit activation with cross entropy error

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to implement gradient calculation for neural networks using backpropagation.
I cannot get it to work with cross entropy error and rectified linear unit (ReLU) as activation.

I managed to get my implementation working for squared error with sigmoid, tanh and ReLU activation functions. Cross entropy (CE) error with sigmoid activation gradient is computed correctly. However, when I change activation to ReLU - it fails. (I'm skipping tanh for CE as it retuls values in (-1,1) range.)

Is it because of the behavior of log function at values close to 0 (which is returned by ReLUs approx. 50% of the time for normalized inputs)?
I tried to mitiage that problem with:

```
log(max(y,eps))
```

but it only helped to bring error and gradients back to real numbers - they are still different from numerical gradient.

I verify the results using numerical gradient:

```
num_grad = (f(W+epsilon) - f(W-epsilon)) / (2*epsilon)
```

The following matlab code presents a simplified and condensed backpropagation implementation used in my experiments:

```
function [f, df] = backprop(W, X, Y)
% W - weights
% X - input values
% Y - target values

act_type='relu';    % possible values: sigmoid / tanh / relu
error_type = 'CE';  % possible values: SE / CE

N=size(X,1); n_inp=size(X,2); n_hid=100; n_out=size(Y,2);
w1=reshape(W(1:n_hid*(n_inp+1)),n_hid,n_inp+1);
w2=reshape(W(n_hid*(n_inp+1)+1:end),n_out, n_hid+1);

% feedforward
X=[X ones(N,1)];
z2=X*w1'; a2=act(z2,act_type); a2=[a2 ones(N,1)];
z3=a2*w2'; y=act(z3,act_type);

if strcmp(error_type, 'CE')   % cross entropy error - logistic cost function
    f=-sum(sum( Y.*log(max(y,eps))+(1-Y).*log(max(1-y,eps)) ));
else % squared error
    f=0.5*sum(sum((y-Y).^2));
end

% backprop
if strcmp(error_type, 'CE')   % cross entropy error
    d3=y-Y;
else % squared error
    d3=(y-Y).*dact(z3,act_type);
end

df2=d3'*a2;
d2=d3*w2(:,1:end-1).*dact(z2,act_type);
df1=d2'*X;

df=[df1(:);df2(:)];

end

function f=act(z,type) % activation function
switch type
    case 'sigmoid'
        f=1./(1+exp(-z));
    case 'tanh'
        f=tanh(z);
    case 'relu'
        f=max(0,z);
end
end

function df=dact(z,type) % derivative of activation function
switch type
    case 'sigmoid'
        df=act(z,type).*(1-act(z,type));
    case 'tanh'
        df=1-act(z,type).^2;
    case 'relu'
        df=double(z>0);
end
end
```

---

**Edit**

After another round of experiments, I found out that using a softmax for the last layer:

```
y=bsxfun(@rdivide, exp(z3), sum(exp(z3),2));
```

and softmax cost function:

```
f=-sum(sum(Y.*log(y)));
```

make the implementaion working for all activation functions including ReLU.

This leads me to conclusion that it is the logistic cost function (binary clasifier) that does not work with ReLU:

```
f=-sum(sum( Y.*log(max(y,eps))+(1-Y).*log(max(1-y,eps)) ));
```

However, I still cannot figure out where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

Every squashing function sigmoid, tanh and softmax (in the output layer) 
means different cost functions.
Then makes sense that a RLU (in the output layer) does not match with the cross entropy cost function.
I will try a simple square error cost function to test a RLU output layer.

The true power of RLU is in the hidden layers of a deep net since it not suffer from gradient vanishing error.

Comment: I came to the similar conclusion after going through several papers on NNs. When I need classification, the output layer for softmax is composed of sigmoid units. Other layers (hidden) remain composed of ReLUs.

Answer (score 0):

If you use gradient descendent you need to derive the activation function to be used later in the back-propagation approach. Are you sure about the 'df=double(z>0)'?. For the logistic and tanh seems to be right.

Further, are you sure about this 'd3=y-Y' ? I would say this is true when you use the logistic function but not for the ReLu (the derivative is not the same and therefore will not lead to that simple equation).

You could use the softplus function that is a smooth version of the ReLU, which the derivative is well known (logistic function).

Comment: The derivative of ReLU funtion is: df=0 for input<= 0 and df=1 for input>0 which in matlab is equivalent to `double(z>0)`.  d3 is the delta of the last layer and it is the correct form. ReLU has advantages over softplus function - check [here](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/icml2010_NairH10.pdf) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the flaw lies in comapring with the numerically computed derivatives. In your derivativeActivation function , you define the derivative of ReLu at 0 to be 0. Where as numerically computing the derivative at x=0 shows it to be
(ReLU(x+epsilon)-ReLU(x-epsilon)/(2*epsilon)) at x =0 which is 0.5. Therefore, defining the derivative of ReLU at x=0 to be 0.5 will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd share my experience I had with similar problem. I too have designed my multi classifier `ANN` in a way that all hidden layers use `RELU` as non-linear activation function and the output layer uses `softmax` function.

My problem was related to some degree to numerical precision of the programming language/platform I was using. In my case I noticed that if I used "plain" `RELU` not only does it kill the gradient but the programming language I used produced the following `softmax` output vectors (this is just a example sample):

```
⎡1.5068230536681645e-35⎤
⎢ 2.520367499064734e-18⎥
⎢3.2572859518007807e-22⎥
⎢                     1⎥
⎢ 5.020155103452967e-32⎥
⎢1.7620297760773188e-18⎥
⎢ 5.216008990667109e-18⎥
⎢ 1.320937038894421e-20⎥
⎢2.7854159049317976e-17⎥
⎣1.8091246170996508e-35⎦
```

Notice the values of most of the elements are close to `0`, but most importantly notice the `1` value in the output.

I used a different `cross-entropy` error function than the one you used. Instead of calculating `log(max(1-y, eps))` I stuck to the basic `log(1-y)`. So given the output vector above, when I calculated `log(1-y)` I got the `-Inf` as a result of `cross-entropy`, which obviously killed the algorithm.

I imagine if your `eps` is not reasonably high enough so that `log(max(1-y, eps))` -> `log(max(0, eps))` doesn't yield way too small `log` output you might be in a similar pickle like myself.

My solution to this problem was to use [Leaky RELU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#Leaky_ReLUs). Once I've started using it, I could carry on using the multi classifier `cross-entropy` as oppose to `softmax-cost` function you decided to try.