# slow training with ReLU layer

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I tried to implement ReLU activation function to Matlab2014b but im not sure if i did it right. I copied pureline.m and +pureling (as a template) folder into working directory. And changed them as shown below:

```
function a = ReLU(n,varargin)
if ischar(n)
    a = nnet7.transfer_fcn(mfilename,n,varargin{:});
  return
end

    a = ReLU.apply(n);
end

function a = apply(n,param)
    a = max(n,0.01*n);
end

function d = da_dn(n,a,param)
    d=ones(size(n));
    d(n<0)=0.01;
    d(n==0)=0.5;
end

function da = forwardprop(dn,n,a,param)
    da = dn;
end
function dn = backprop(da,n,a,param)
    dn = da;
end

function s = isScalar
    s = true;
end

function flag = discontinuity(n,param)
    flag = false(1,size(n,2));
end

function or = outputRange
    or = [0 inf];
end

function ir = activeInputRange
    ir = [-inf inf];
end

function param = parameterInfo
    param = [];
end

function t = type
    t = 'transfer_fcn';
end

function name = name()
    name = 'ReLU';
end
```

And implemented it to NN with
`net.layers{1}.transferFcn='ReLU'`. It seems to work but training NN with ReLU took 3 times longer (on average) than with other activation functions like `tansig` hiperbolic tangent or `pureline` linear. I tested it with `trainlm` Levenber-Marquardt and `trainscg` scaled conjugate gradient. Time comparison results are the same.

Actualy it is Leaky ReLU. Derivate based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/32545990/6718612 , though looks like dn/da=0.5 for n=0 doesn't make a difference.
What did i missed?

Edit: i found that ReLU already exists in Matlab2014b and is called 'poslin'. It works as well as others built-in.